# note: expected 'float *' but argument is of type 'int *'

Tags: c, types, floating-point, int

I have a warning
note: expected 'float *' but argument is of type 'int *' 
My program is

```
#include <stdio.h> //header file

void foo(float *);

int main()
{
    int i = 10, *p = &i;
    foo(&i);
}

void foo(float *p)
{
    printf("%f\n", *p);
}
```

Output is 0.000 000
Why?

Comment: isn't the warning text already obvious about what's wrong?

Comment: What's it about the warning that you didn't understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The foo function expects a parameter of type `int *` (pointer to integer), not of type `float *` (pointer to float). Change the data type `float` to an `int` and substitute `"%d"` instead of `"%f"` to get rid of the warning.

Answer (score 1):

As warning says, you're passing to `foo()` a pointer to `int`, but `foo()` expects a pointer to `float`. So, or you declare `i` as `float`, or change the parameter of `foo()` as `int*`.